# Basic Firebase database save

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Anyone looking at this the below is the correct answer and I had everything setup correctly.
I still dont no what the issue is.
I was loggin in with facebook, using that to create a firebaseuser object.
and then sending the below as test data.
I've found it to be an intermittent issue. Uninstalling the app from the device and redeploying often fixes the issue. 
very odd

Im actually struggling to get the example to work.

So basic.. set value....

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Log.d(TAG, "db ref: "+database.getReference());
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

When I go into the database console I cant see the values I sent.
My log is returning a reference to the db though.
I've also set my rules up as public to be on the safe side.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Very likely your database only allows read/write by authenticated users and your app doesn't sign the user in. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied/37404116#37404116

Comment: is there any child name 'message' ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen umm my rules are set up as read/write... {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy do i need to do anything in the console to except a write? It currently just says the name of my db and then "null"

Comment: Hmmm... those rules look good. If you attach an [completion callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#receive_a_completion_callback) to `setValue()` it will show you if (and why) the write is failing. `myRef.setValue(...).addOnFailureListener()`

Comment: If you need a working read/write working android please refer to this link https://github.com/frk93/FirebaseBasics Make sure to add the app to your database and overwrite the rules

Comment: [along with the other solutions provided, try to add proper latest version of dependencies in the build.gradle file.... this worked for me .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O28c.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Actually you are referencing a child 'message' which is logically not there,

If you want to name you root of the database simply follow the steps

```
DatabaseReference myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //Getting root reference
myRef1.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

and if you want to give some value to your child in `database`, Make sure you have a child in your `database`

```
DatabaseReference myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //Getting root reference
DatabaseReference myRef = myRef1.child("message"); //Write your child reference if any
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

It will `overwrite` the value of your child to 'Hello World'

Go to `Firebase console` and create a project and give it a valid packageName which you will use. and **download google-service.json** file and add this file to `app folder` by changing your Android View to Project View.

Add these lines into Project:Gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Add these into App:Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM OF YOUR APP GRADLE

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Note : Do overwrite the rules in your database . If you are not implementing login authentication.**

```
{
  "rules": 
   {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
   }
}
```

> And add this line in Application or in onCreate of Activity

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad... No idea whats going on to be honest. "myRef1.getDatabase().getReference()" returns the url to my database... so i can see it, just aint writing to it. Set up my rules as public as well.

Comment: The answer is perfect just make your what i describe here you must follow and please refer to this link also https://github.com/frk93/FirebaseBasics

Comment: I checked your example Muhammad, ive added the         myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
to my code and it does return the values sent. however nothing updates on the web firebase console. does yours?

Comment: Make sure you have required dependencies and overwrite rules in database in your firebase database console

Comment: You guys can refer to this gist as well for implementation:
https://github.com/frk93/FirebaseBasics

Answer (score 0):

seems, i found the answer.
It helps me!

I have used before android studio version 1.5
And that's why (maybe not) but i could't upgrade required firebase libs to 9.0.2
All this time i have used 9.0.0

So firstly i upgrade my android studio to updated stable version 2.2 and then update version of dependencies to next ones:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
```

And now all values are saved to database from android app.

So do two things:
1. update android studio to last stable version
2. update firebase required libs versions

Hope this answer will help

Answer (score 0):

Try including the URL of the database.

```
String strURL="https://testfirebase-0123-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/";
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(strURL);
```

Comment: I suggest to you an example link. Also, this doesn't seems to answer the question. Can you explain how this will fix the issue/why he is getting this ?