# firebase can not save to database

Tags: android, database, firebase

Sorry for my english.
I just started to use firebase in my android app.

The problem is the same as in [Basic Firebase database save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421172/basic-firebase-database-save/37644204#37644204)  Here the author seems does't find solution yet.

I have given public access to databse (.read and .write - true) security rules.
Database reference is shown correct. And when try to save some value to existed path (for example to "message" ) - no result.

Firebase setup correctly (all required dependencies and files).

By the way,  users are authenticated by custom auth system properly.

Have no idea, why i can't save value to existed path.. (

Comment: Any errors coming back from Firebase? Also, provide your save code.

Answer (score 0):

Right now i get positive result.

I have used before android studio version 1.5
And that's why (maybe not) but i could't upgrade required firebase libs to 9.0.2
All this time i have used 9.0.0

So firstly i upgrade my android studio to updated stable version 2.2 and then update version of dependencies to next ones:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
```

And now all values are saved to database from android app.

So do two things:
1. update android studio to last stable version
2. update firebase required libs versions

Hope this answer will help