# 'setValue' Android Studio shows error

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

we are trying to connect `Firebase` to Android Studio. The first two steps are marked with a green tick, but for some reason when we try to set the value of myRef, Android Studio says 'Cannot resolve symbol `'setValue'`. `'setValue'` is coloured red.

Screenshot of code:

[image]

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");` is misplaced.  It must be inside a method body.  Move it inside the `onCreate()` or `onStart()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call `push()` to generate a unique key for the new data:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() 
mDatabase.push().setValue("Hello, World!");
```

check [this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421977/2826147)

Answer (score 0):

Include the URL of your database in getInstance()

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://testfirebase-98765-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/");
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```