# How to write a key with its map values in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store users information by adding a key with its map object

```
private void createUserData() {
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "test begin",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

    //set fields data
    Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<>();
    userData.put("userId", "test id ");
    userData.put("email", "as@gmail");
    userData.put("userName", "abdo");

    usersRef.child("userkey").setValue(userData);

    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "test end",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

when i click the button to trigger this code, the both Toast objects show up but no node added to users node.
whats wrong with this code to write data to firebase database ?

Comment: Most likely you're not authenticated and your security rules don't allow anonymous writes (since the default security rules for the dashboard only allow authenticated access). See the first blue box on the [page on saving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied/37404116#37404116).

Comment: in the dashboard a warning appears  "Your security rules are defined as public, anyone can read or write to your database" 
 {
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}

Comment: Hmm... you might want to add a completion listener to see if the client consider the write "completed": https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#receive_a_completion_callback

Comment: I've added a completion listener but it never triggered.
usersRef.child("userkey").setValue(newUser, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() { ...

Comment: do u already have 'userkey' node in the database? if so it will not uptade with same values. you should use variable keys or .push to auto generate keys.

Comment: I want to set the key node with its values programmatically, i don't want to use push method. the problem is the completion listener is not triggered at all to know if the data added or not!.

Comment: If your completion listener doesn't get triggered, your app is not connected to the Firebase servers.

Comment: I've tried usersRef.push().setValue(map) and it saved correctly but the callback not triggered. 
And i want to put the user's email as a key instead of a push.

Comment: I figured out that keys must not contain special characters, so thats why data are not being saved, But I still wondering why listener doesn't get triggered!.

Answer (score -1):

1.change the `<String, String>` as `<String, Object>`

```
  Map<String, Object> userData = new HashMap<>();
  userData.put("userId", "test id ");
  userData.put("email", "as@gmail");
  userData.put("userName", "abdo");
    
  usersRef.child("userkey").updateChildren(userData);
```

2.change the firebase database get instance like `FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://yourdatabasename-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")`

recieved from [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806876/firebase-realtime-database-connection-killed-different-region)

**might be the database region problem like below**

Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://databasename-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app

Comment: Please format your code/answer correctly and provide steps to effectively check that your hypothesis is correct. As it is, it looks like a stab in the dark.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).