# unable to save files to firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an app that uses firebase for authentication and database. This is my first app using firebase and I am unable to save files to firebase database. I am not getting any error in the console when I run the app but it is not saving anything to firebase. I read the firebase docs and followed the instruction but I am unable to get it to work. Help would be appreciated. Here is my code 
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase

```
class AddVC: UIViewController {

 var refAttractions: DatabaseReference! //defining firebase database reference

@IBOutlet weak var addedlbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptioninfo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryinfo: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        // accessing nodes of refAttractiions
     refAttractions = Database.database().reference().child("Attractions")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func submitbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    addAttractions()
}
func addAttractions(){
    let key = refAttractions.childByAutoId().key //creating id for the  attraction. 
    let attraction = ["id": key,
                      "category": categoryinfo.text! as String,
                      "description": descriptioninfo.text! as String ]

    refAttractions.child(key).setValue(attraction)
 }



@IBAction func backbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Also, I have changed the rules in my firebase database to true for both read and write. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your database rules? Look at this questions for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934817/setvalue-method-not-updating-to-firebase-database

Comment: it is true for both .read and .write.

Comment: The post didn't help me solve my problem. Can you please help me?