# Permission Denied to Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, permission-denied

I'm trying to use Firebase Realtime database following Firebase's guide online but I can't get any updates on the database as my permission is being denied. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've even set the rules to read and write to true.

The code inside onClickListener is below:

```
Button vDetails = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.enter_vechile_details);
vDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        myRef.child("Customers").child("Drivers").setValue("Name").addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signUp: set customer name" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SignUpCustomerFragment()).commit();
    }
});
```

**This is inside a fragment** and the button completes those statements first before it begins the transaction for the fragment replacement.

This is the rules in Firebase:

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true
   }
}
```

As I am new to JSON, I've also tried with a comma at the end of ".write"

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true,
   }
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzall$1.onComplete(Unknown Source)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahq$20.run(Unknown Source)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
09-10 04:32:46.274 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
09-10 04:32:46.276 16594-16594/com.buildingstories.sabbib.xpose W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

I've been at this all day and I have no idea what's wrong since I followed the Firebase guide.

Comment: attach a `addOnFailureListener` to `myRef.setValue()` to see what error you are getting.

Comment: post you Customer class code and real time database structure from firebase console

Comment: Most likely you don't have permission to write the data. Read this explanation on [how to detect errors when writing a value on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database#t=201609091416264266996)

Comment: You are right, I am not getting permission. I have set the rules to allow read and write data but its still not allowing me. anything I can do to debug it further? I have a printStackTrace but not making much of it @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: refer this link it will work for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/37404116/4427519

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a child for "drive" and push the Customer class as given below code and remember to create Empty Constructor in your Customer Class:

```
       FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Drivers");

       Customer customer = new Customer();
       customer.setFirstName(fullName.getText().toString());//fullName is EditText

       myRef.child("drive").push().setValue(customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set topic in child for update value

Pass Value in constructor don't set.

```
Customer customer = new Customer(fullName.getText().toString()); // Pass values here in constructor
//customer.setFirstName(fullName.getText().toString());

myRef.child("Drivers").setValue(customer);
```

Comment: I am doing it but nothing :/

Comment: set value in constructor directly

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HashMap` to push your values as and add a `onFailureListener` so you can see what `error` you are getting:

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Drivers");

       Customer customer = new Customer();
       customer.setFirstName(fullName.getText().toString());//fullName is EditText

       Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
       map.add("drive",customer);

       myRef.push().setValue(map).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

**NOTE**: Make sure `Customer` class has an empty constructor or `Firebase` won't be able to `Serialize` your class.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will set the Drivers class to "drive"
.

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

db.child("Drivers").setValue("drive");
```

note that push() and setValue() are different. you can read more about saving data on your Realtime Firebase Database [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data)

Comment: Please check the edit, its a persmission issue @pastillas