# Access firebase database from web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to access my Firebase database from web:

Config copied from console:

```
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AI***********************************98",
    authDomain: "t*****.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://t*****.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "t*****",
    storageBucket: "t*****.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "224202513016"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

However calling:

```
firebase.database().ref('/calibration/temperature').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot);
});
```

Results in:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: permission_denied at /calibration/temperature: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

My rules in DB:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I've tried to use different API keys, or restrict them to specific web page - unfortunately with no luck.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `auth != null` in a security rule will deny access to non-authenticated users.

You've called `initializeApp`, but unless you've subsequently called one of the [`signIn...` methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth), you won't have an authenticated user and access will be denied by the security rules.