# Can't upload to Firebase-Storage/Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload .mp3 files via Firebase-storage but I am running into an issue with the permissions/rules. Every time I upload I get a console warning

"**FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied**"

and

"**firebase.js:478 Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied**"

Despite these errors, I still find the file in Firebase-storage. However, these errors prevent my code from running smoothly. I have found that changing the *rules* in my *Firebase-Database* allows me to upload with no issues.

By changing the rules in the *Firebase-Database* to be:

```
{
    "rules": {
       ".read": "true",
       ".write": "true"
     }
 }
```

**I am able to upload the .mp3 with no issues.** Obviously for security reasons I can't have these rules always being true.

My storage rules are

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a connection between Firebase-Storage and the Firebase-Database/rules? Or how to resolve my permissions errors?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied

Comment: That lead me on the correct path, thanks a ton @Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue I was having was not related to the Storage. I had not supplied a rule for part of the data I was posting to the database. That is why the errors would not show up if I added a ".write": "true".