# Database error: Permission denial error in FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to integrate Firebase in my Android application.I have followed the steps as documented by the fire base. When I am trying to send data, I am not able to send. I am getting below error in callback

```
**Permission denied**
```

And the error code in callback is **-3**

I have searched relative answers over stack overflow in many places and it did not work for me. As this is the very famous thread

[Firebase Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied)

In this thread it is mentioned that I need to add below code in database section where the rules are defined. And below is the code

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
}
}
```

When I went to the place as mentioned in that thread (**went to database section and then rules area**) I already found some piece of code. And that code is mentioned below

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
}
}
```

My Problem is I am getting permission denied error when commnuicating the database. When I am adding code as mentioned in the thread, Fire base is not recognizing that code. What is the right place to place code if there is a need? Or why am I getting that error? Am I missing something.

Below is the code I am using for firebase communication

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = mDatabaseReference.child("users");

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    //auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    btnSignIn = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    inputEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnResetPassword = findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setUserType(1);

            mDatabaseReference.child("users").setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            dataSnapshot.exists();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            databaseError.getCode();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });


        }
    });
}
```

NOTE: **setValue at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied** this is log I am getting.

Comment: What's appearing in your logcat?

Comment: I am getting only this in log cat setValue at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: what was the reason behind down voting? May I know please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied)

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari did you even completely compare and checked with my question and code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules say only authorized users can read and write from database but in your code you are trying to insert data with unregistered user

1- Either register user with `firebase` before inserting data

or

2- Allow unauthorized users also to write in database

Rule:-

```
{
  "rules": {

  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In authentication tab, I have allowed anonymous user option. Is that I needed to do for unauthorize user?

Comment: I have created an app over firebase and added json file in my android app. any other stepp still required for registering user.

Comment: try the rule I mentioned above

Comment: where to add above code...I am still figuring this thing out? can you please guide me actually where to place the code?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed added pic

Comment: ohhh  i got you.... I found the problem ... on the top of the rule there is a drop down ... it was selected with cloud firebase beta.... when I changed this to real time data base... and that is bingo...

Comment: Yes, you answer definitely helped me. At least pointed me to the right direction. Thanks budyy. :)