# What is the best way to do a simple post request from flutter app to firebase?

Tags: http, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I am trying to do a simple post request from a flutter app to a firebase database.
This is my code:

```dart
child: RaisedButton(
  child:Text('A firebase'),
  textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  onPressed: () {
    var url = "https://gip-reports.firebaseio.com/reporte.json";
    http.post(url, body: {"name": "doodle", "color": "blue"})
      .then((response) {
         print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
         print("Response body: ${response.body}");
       });
  },
),
```

The problem is, when I use this code, the cmd shows this error:

```
I/flutter (16602): Response status: 401
I/flutter (16602): Response body: {
I/flutter (16602):   "error" : "Permission denied"
I/flutter (16602): }
```

How can I get my app to post to firebase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied)

Comment: What you've written is a post request. Maybe you're missing some headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting permissions to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

would work.

The best way  of doing this however, would be to authenticate your users using the Firebase Auth package: [Firebase_Auth package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) (even if you sign them in anonymously) and then to use the Firebase_Database package: [Firebase_Database Package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database) to load data in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easy. I did not know about the default pemissions of realtime databases of firebase. The default permissions are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But if I want to try doing http request in the development time, I can change the permissions to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

You can change this in the database section of firebase -> rules

I got the answer thanks to this post [Firebase Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied)