# Save innerHTML data and input data to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code where I want to save data to firebase. I want to be able to save selected meeting to firebase along with input in form. I am new to react and stuck at the moment to get further with my code so some suggestions what I can do would be much appreciated.

[This is how my app looks like and with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUKuc.png)

I have conected firebase and I am able to push up data but cant save data from my properties as handleClick..

[Error when I try to submit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNASr.png)

```
import './App.css';
import firebase from 'firebase';
const uuid = require('uuid');


class App extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            // gör strängar av state
            this.state = {
                uid: uuid.v1(),
                meeting:'',
                name:'',
                email:'',
            };

            // binder propertys till click funktion 
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
            this.inputData = this.inputData.bind(this);

            // kopplar databas
            var config = {
                apiKey: "",
                authDomain: "",
                databaseURL: "",
                projectId: "",
                storageBucket: "",
                messagingSenderId: ""
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            // console.log(firebase);

            // skapar databasen lokalt med referens ref
            var database = firebase.database();
            var ref = database.ref('meeting');

            // variabel data med sträng id
            var data ={
                id: '',
            }
            // Pushar upp data till databas
            ref.push(data);
        }

        // hämtar klick för mötes knappar och skriver ut text i knappar
        handleClick = (e) =>{
            console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
            alert('Du har valt ett möte');
        }

        // hämtar API för olika möten 
        componentDidMount(){
            fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c9cdca03300004d003f2151')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                let meetings = []
                json.forEach(meeting => {
                    if(new Date(meeting.startDate).getDay() !== new Date(meeting.endDate).getDay()){
                        let day1 = {
                            activity:meeting.activity,
                            location:meeting.location,
                            startDate:meeting.startDate,
                        }
                        let day2 = {
                            activity:meeting.activity,
                            location:meeting.location,
                            endDate:meeting.endDate,
                        }

                        meetings.push(day1,day2)

                    }else{
                        meetings.push(meeting)
                    }

                });
                console.log(meetings)
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded:true,
                    items: meetings,
                })
            });

            // import firebase och ref sträng
            firebase
            .database()
            .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
            .on('value', snap => console.log('from db', snap.val()));
        }


        // hämtar ny data 
    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.name});

    }

    // hämtar ref och skriver ut sträng med set till firebase
    handleSubmit(e){
        alert('Er bokning är bekräftad: ' + this.state.value);
        console.log('Du har bekräftat er bokning')
        e.preventDefault();
        firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
        .set({
            meeting: this.state.meeting,
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

// knyter input text till property
    inputData (_e){
        const meeting = this.refs.meeting1.value;
        const name = this.refs.name1.value;
        const email = this.refs.email1.value;
        this.setState({ meeting, name, email});
    }

  render() {

        var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded){
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        else {

    return (
            <>
      <div className="App">
                <div className="AppHeader">
                    <h1>Boka ditt möte nedan</h1>

                </div>
        <ul>

                    {items.map((item,i) => (
                        <li key={i}>

                    {/* kopplar handleClick till onChange*/}
                            <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} onChange={this.inputData} ref="meeting1" className="select">
                            {item.activity}<br/>
                            Starttid: {item.startDate}<br/>
                            Sluttid: {item.endDate}<br/> 
                            Plats: {item.location}<br/>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    ))}

                    </ul>

      </div>

        <div className="selectedMeeting">Fyll i dina uppgifter och bekräfta</div>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="bookingSection">
                    <label>
                        Name:
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.inputData}
                        ref="name1"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        E-mail:
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.inputData}
                        ref="email1"/>
                    </label>
                    <input className="confirm" type="submit" value="Bekräfta" />
                </form>
                <div className="viewSelect"></div>
                </>
    );
    }

}
}

export default App;
```

I get an error when I try to save the meeting, name, email to firebase.

Comment: Hi, could you share the error message? Also, could you cut your code sample a bit (just keep it minimum that describe your problem)?

Comment: I have shared the error message in "Error when I try to submit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the database is only accessible to authenticated users.

```
'rules': {
  '.read': 'auth != null',
  '.write': 'auth != null'
}
```

You have to define the rules on the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com)

You can allow to read or write the databse to everyone under development and then if needed add more rules (I suggest you to get familiar with the firebase rules):

```
'rules': {
  '.read': true,
  '.write': true
}
```

This should solve your issue for now.
Also, if you are new to React, I suggest you to learn to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) and combine it with [React Redux Firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase), these will help you a lot alongside with React.

Comment: Hi thanks I changed the rules on firebase so it works now. I will look more on Redux. Thanks!

Comment: I would appreciate that if you accept my answer then :D

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean.

Comment: The check mark beside my answer, if you think my aswer was usefuel and helped you out, you can select it as an answer for you question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full explanation to this problem in [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37404116/6138595) . It is also explained how to handle proper sign-In correctly.