# probelm with angular and firebase cloud messaging

Tags: angular, firebase

I was trying to work with angular and firebase cloud messaging, and I followed this example step by step, then I am stucked with this error on the console. Can anyone help?
https://medium.com/@a.adendrata/push-notifications-with-angular-6-firebase-cloud-massaging-dbfb5fbc0eeb

**Unhandled Promise rejection: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied ; Zone:  ; Task: WebSocket.addEventListener:message ; Value: Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied**
    `at index.cjs.js:13076
    at exceptionGuard (index.cjs.js:690)
    at Repo.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Repo.callOnCompleteCallback (index.cjs.js:13067)
    at index.cjs.js:12880
    at index.cjs.js:12019
    at PersistentConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (index.cjs.js:12052)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can show more code, this would be very helpful

this error is for permissions in firebase you can read this post

[Firebase Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied)

you can try change this in firebase

{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}