# Flutter FCM push notification - Foreground Notification tap event

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, foregroundnotification

Am using *firebase_messaging* and *flutter_local_notifications* packages, Currently am able to get the notification data when the user tap the notification when the app is in the background. How can i listen to the tap event when the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, hope its help you:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
});
```

I copy that code from the Flutter Fire documentation, I will put the link here
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage

Comment: Hi @Ananda thanks for the answer but this event is triggered when a notification is received but i need it when the user tap the notification.

Comment: Oh sorry about it. You can try this, maybe it will help in some ways.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650892/flutter-how-to-do-a-task-after-user-open-push-notif-message-fcm

Comment: @AnandaPramono did u got solution for your post?