# PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, error-handling, react-redux, single-page-application, react-redux-firebase

I am developing a single page application using react, redux and firebase. When a user logged in he gets an error.

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
▼ 5 stack frames were expanded.
(anonymous function)
E:/React/React Projects-2/src/core/Repo.ts:632
exceptionGuard
E:/React/React Projects-2/src/core/util/util.ts:585
Repo.callOnCompleteCallback
E:/React/React Projects-2/src/core/Repo.ts:624
(anonymous function)
E:/React/React Projects-2/src/core/Repo.ts:476
(anonymous function)
E:/React/React Projects-2/src/core/PersistentConnection.ts:444
▲ 5 stack frames were expanded.
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

Comment: Check your database/firestore rules and make sure users have read/write access where applicable. The answers on this thread go into more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied

Comment: The rules for the application are "rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}"

Comment: I have changed the firebase realtime database rules now it is working. Thank you very much. @A.Cucci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to the firebase realtime database rules.  You can get rid of this just by changing the rules.